# How to get power off event on Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

Help is needed:
 I need to know if TV was power off in my app to reload the app. I can not find anything in the documentation that can help me
The probles is the application does not close after power off and after power on the application is in the same state as before power off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monitor it with listener visibilityChange.

The documentation for JS is here:
http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/fundamentals/multitasking